# How to auto check checkboxes using Twig template?

Tags: php, twig

I want to auto-check check boxes in the HTML. I've managed to get this to work, but it's kinda messy in the template:

```
<ul>
    {% for tag in tags %}
        {% set selected = false %}
        {% for article_tag in article.tags %}
            {% if article_tag.id == tag.id %}
                {% set selected = true %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="{{ tag.id }}" {% if selected %}checked{% endif %}> {{ tag.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So the data I'm loading in is like this (in JSON format):

```
[
    'tags' => [
        {'id'=> 1, 'name'=>'Travel'},
        {'id'=> 2, 'name'=>'Cooking'},
    ],
    'article' => {
        'tags' => [
            {'id'=> 1, 'name'=>'Travel'},
        ],
    }
]
```

Also, I'm not using Symfony (I'm using Slim's Twig library) so not sure if Symfony has some stuff in it's framework for doing stuff with Twig. If so, it won't work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the article is an array, so or you need to cycle on it for every tags array that contain or you simply access on it of the first element as follow:

```
    {% for article_tag in article[0].tags %}
```

Instead of:

```
    {% for article_tag in article.tags %}
```

[See the result on this working twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/w0qgxs)

Hope this help

Comment: "article" is an array, but a PHP associative array - in JSON that would be a Object I guess. I've updated my question and given the data example in JSON format for PHP associated arrays for clarity. The issue isn't that it isn't working, it is working. But it seems that I have to have nested loops in my view which seems like much logic in the template - I was hoping that Twig had some build in mechanism to handle this as it's a fairly common thing when outputting check boxes. Unless this is the only means to achieve this then I'll stick with it. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Martyn now i understand your question, in symfony, there is the form component that manage this behaviour for you (i don't know how slim manage a form....) . For get code more cleaning you can incapsulate this in a macro or a twig function. Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeh having a search online I could see that Symfony had additional features that the framework seemed to include. I don't think Slim offers much. I'll have a think about macros and see if that would work out well, maybe help to keep things tidier.